# Flutter nested navigation and getting data from 'pop'

Tags: flutter

I am using nested navigation in my Flutter app, and I need to update my previous screen after popping off the stack.

I have my nested navigation set up in screen A with:

```
  Route _onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    late Widget page;
    switch (screenB.name) {
      case routeScreenB:
        page = ScreenB(
          infoFromScreenC: infoObject,
        );
        break;
      case routeScreenC:
        page = ScreenC();
        break;
```

In `ScreenC`, I have:

```
Navigator.pop(context, infoObject);
```

In ScreenA, I push ScreenC as such:

```
final result = await _navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(routeScreenC);
this.infoObject = result as Map;
```

I can retrieve the value of `infoObject` in ScreenA, but how do I update it in ScreenB?

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting to the additional info
I would try something like this, although I'm not totally familiar with the context.

```
var infoObject;

_navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(routeScreenC).then((value){setState(_) {infoObject = value as Map}});
```

According to the flutter docs

"pushNamed() Returns a Future that completes to the result value passed to pop when the pushed route is popped off the navigator."
So this might work

Comment: Sorry my question was incomplete. I updated about - I am already getting that data, but I'm not sure how to update the screen that is displaying after the pop

Comment: You can call setState in the callback and the return value is your infoObject.
I haven't really used pushnamed() but the concept is basically the same in my opinion.